# Cannot cast from Throwable to MyException

Tags: java, exception

I am catching an `Exception` and trying to examine the `getCause()` of it, performing some further actions if the `cause` is a of type `MyException`, defined in another library.

I am getting this Eclipse (compiler?) error when trying to check if `e.getCause() instanceof MyException`:

> Incompatible conditional operand types Throwable and MyException

When attempting to cast `(MyException) e.getCause()`, I get:

> Cannot cast from Throwable to MyException

I can compiled `e.getCause().getClass().equals(MyException.class)`, and this does return `true`.

Comment: Any chance the MyException class was declared twice and you're not using the one you're supposed to use?

Comment: I just encounter a similar question, it takes me several minutes. `Exception e = null; if(e instanceof InvocationTargetException)` it reports this error, the answer to this question is that: import the class you use.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is that `MyException` inherited from an `Exception` in an external library, but the top-level project didn't include that external library. I discovered this when I created a `private class` that `extend`ed `MyException`, and got an inconsistent type hierarchy error.

Comment: In future questions, post the **actual** code and the **actual** error.

Comment: I agree with @BalusC. Actually, it would be extremely prudent of you to edit your original question to include the actual error so that search engines can index it and other people in similar circumstances will be able to find this solution.

Comment: Sure thing, that was my hope.