# Java custom exception class

Tags: java, exception

I am having a rather trivial problem creating my own exception class. I have extending it and am trying to recieve a double in the constructor but I keep getting errors.

Error inside of bankaccount @withdraw "incompatible types: InsufficientFundsException cannot be converted to throwable"

Exception class:

```
    public class InsufficientFundsException extends RuntimeException {

    private double shortFall;   

    public InsufficientFundsException(double a) {
        super("Insufficient funds");
        shortFall = a;
    }

    public double getAmount() { return shortFall; }

}
```

Bank Account class:

```
public class BankAccount {

    private int accountNumber;
    private double balance;

    // Class constructor
    public BankAccount(int account) {
        accountNumber = account;
        balance = 0.0;
    }

    public int getAccountNumber() {

        return accountNumber;
    }

    public double getBalance()
    {
        return balance;
    }

    public void deposit(double b) {
        balance += b;
    }

    public void withdraw(double w) throws InsufficientFundsException {

        double difference;
        if(w > balance) {
            difference = w - balance;           
        } else {
            balance -= w;   
        }
    }
```

I would like to withdraw money unless the withdraw is greater than the current balance. In which case I want to throw an exception. I also tried to throw and exception inside of the if but I get:

constructor InsufficientFundsException in class InsufficientFundsException cannot be applied to gived types;
required: no arguments
found: double
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

```
 public void withdraw(double w)  {

        double difference;
        if(w > balance) {
            difference = w - balance; 
            Exception ex =  new InsufficientFundsException(difference);
        } else {
            balance -= w;   
        }
    }
```

I only have the one constructor though. Any advice or help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you have more than one class called `InsufficientFundsException`?

Comment: You should `throw` the new exception you've created.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
throw new InsufficientFundsException(difference);
```

in place of

```
Exception ex =  new InsufficientFundsException(difference);
```

That's generally how exceptions are thrown.

Updated code snippet...

```
public void withdraw(double w) throws InsufficientFundsException {

    double difference;
    if(w > balance) {
        difference = w - balance;    
        throw new InsufficientFundsException(difference);
    } else {
        balance -= w;   
    }
}
```

Ran with...

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    BankAccount account = new BankAccount(1);
    account.withdraw(5.0);
}
```

Got....

```
Exception in thread "main" com.misc.help.InsufficientFundsException:     Insufficient funds
at com.misc.help.BankAccount.withdraw(BankAccount.java:32)
at com.misc.help.BankAccount.main(BankAccount.java:40)
```

Comment: I have but I just tried it again for verification I get "constructor InsufficientFundsException in class InsufficientFundsException cannot be applied to given types"

Comment: Just added my code change. I got the intended exception.

Comment: Thanks shrirrine but I am still having an issue. I am thinking maybe I declared the actual exception class wrong? The error right now in the method signature is incompatible types: InsufficientFundsException cannot be converted to Throwable.

Comment: Your exception class declaration in the original post is fine. That's what I ran in Eclipse. Could this be related... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4218478/cannot-cast-from-throwable-to-myexception

Comment: Recompiled my code in Netbeans seems to work now. Looks like it was a hierarchy issue. Thanks for your time shirrine!